# "Getting marry" or "getting married"?

Tags: sentence-structure

Which sentence is correct and more natural?

> 1. We are getting marry.

or

> 2. We are getting married.

Is '*Married*' an adjective here?

Comment: 1. is just not correct so no comparison is possible. Married is the past participle of "marry". Please look [at this answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/44694/12918).

Answer (score 1):

"Get married" is a common verb phrase, and is suitable here, so "We are getting married" is correct.

"*Getting marry" is incorrect.

## More details

A discussion of terms related to marriage [here](http://www.5minuteenglish.com/apr2.htm) can help clarify the usage.

[This answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/44694/164776) discusses the grammatical aspects of "get married".

Answer (score -1):

> We are getting married.

This is the correct sentence. It is used as a **Future Perfect** tense verb.

Comment: Future perfect is "we will have got married"... "getting married" is in  the *present progressive* tense.